# How to reassign the values to a textbox after navigating to the backpage in Windows8 metro apps

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have created two Pages Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml in windows8 metro apps.

I have created one textbox and Hyperlink in Page1.xaml. Clicking that Hyperlink button after entering some text in textbox in Page1.xaml. Then its navigating to the Page2.xaml. In Page2.xaml I am going to show the text which was entered in the Page1.xaml textbox.

Here after coming to the Page2.xaml I am clicking the back button for going to previous page Page1.xaml. Here I want to show the text in the textbox which I have entered earlier.

But I am getting error when clicking the back button.

Could you please provide me the solution for displaying the text in TextBox of Page1.xaml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make code available across different script scopes is to use a WinJS namespace.

For example, in page1.js, you would have:

```
(function(){
    function setText(){
        var mytext = "";

        WinJS.Namespace.define("page1", {
           text: mytext 
        });
    }
})();
```

in page2.js, you'd put the text in that namespace:

```
(function(){

   page1.text = "page 2 text!";

})();
```

Back in page 1, you can retrieve that value later on:

```
(function(){

    function setText(){
        var mytext = "";

        WinJS.Namespace.define("page1", {
           text: mytext 
        });
    }

    function getText() {
      document.querySelector("#myTextField").value = page1.text;
    }
})();
```

I'd suggest being a bit more formal about what you put in namespaces, but that's one way to do it.

Comment: Could you please provide the solution in C#.

Thnks.

Comment: In XAML/C# it's standard view model stuff. Make each page use the same view model instance and bind to the same property. Or if you're really lazy, create a static variable. :)